# Disabling session for parent controller but keep it enabled for called child actions from other controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know if something like this is possible in ASP MVC ?

1. Disable session for a controller

   ```
   [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
   public class NoSessionController : Controller
   {
   }
   ```
2. The actions will load some views which eventually will call another action from another controller. The controller will have the session enabled. The called action will load/ store values in session.

   ```
   [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]
   public class WithSessionController : Controller
   {
      [ChildActionOnly]
      public ViewResult Actionname()
      {
          Session["abc"]="def";
      }
   }
   ```

Is it possible to have something like this? From what it looks at first sight, the session setting from the nosessioncontroller will override the setting from the withsessioncontroller?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now I found the only solution is to remove ChildActionOnly attribute.

After that SessionState attribute is not required anymore and the session is OK.